# How do I modify the following regex to match on the first occurrence of a digit in a year (e.g. 2020)?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the following regex expression but it fails to match on only the 1st occurrence of the digit "2":

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])[2A-Z]
```

For example, if I use the string "fifa2020" it will match on both 2's. I only want it to match on the first 2.

How do I modify the existing regex (I need the parts of it that are currently working) to achieve what I want?

https://regex101.com/r/gi0IrZ/1

Comment: It depends on the language, but you can remove the global flag https://regex101.com/r/aRuJDx/1

Comment: Using groups: `^(.*?[a-zA-Z0-9])?([2A-Z].*)`

Comment: It can easily happen that your programming language has a method to catch the first match only.

Comment: anyone know the best way to do this in kotlin? I think kotlin defaults to global

Comment: Maybe using find https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find.html